# Can't put formatted tag names in tag wiki excerpt?

Tags: discussion, markdown, formatting, tag-wikis

If you enter the text `[tag:tag]` in the tag wiki textbox, it produces [tag](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tag).

If you enter the text `[tag:tag]` in the tag wiki excerpt textbox, it produces `[tag:tag]`.

> Why can't you include formatted tag names in the tag wiki excerpt? Both the tag wiki and the tag wiki excerpt make use of MathJax, but why don't they both have the tag name capability?

Comment: Related (to some extent): http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/6574/latex-in-tag-wikis

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is (by-design).

The sidebar when you are editing a tag wiki contains the following:

> The tag wiki **excerpt** is a brief plain text introduction to the topic that the tag represents. ...

The important point above is *plain text*, which means no Markdown.  So not only are [tag-links](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tag-links) not available, but even **bold**, *italic*, `code`, and [hyperlinks](http://www.stackexchange.com) are not processed.

Comment: MathJax gets processed, though.

Comment: @Asaf: Interesting. This will probably be due to the logical design of the site, with MathJax being enabled throughout a page, and SE being more easily able to limit where the Markdown is rendered.

Comment: It wasn't always like that, and it took some time before the feature was implemented, but it's been like that for quite some time now. (See link by Martin in the comments to the main question.)